# Upload Mirror quick-start Java project to App Engine:

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-glass, google-mirror-api

I have problem with uploading mirorapi quick-start to App Engine. Currently I can run locally, but I don't know how to upload it to appengine. Based on this [book](http://books.google.com/books?id=d-fhAwAAQBAJ&dq=Beginning%20Google%20Glass%20Development&hl=en&sa=X&ei=NzgZVOnZFsHYaszhgpAC&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAA), I have to upload with appcfg.sh:
[image]

Because I'm using windows, so I run it with cmd. But when I executed this command:

```
appcfg.sh update C:...\mirror-quickstart-java-master\mirror-quickstart-java-master
```

The system ask me to open application. I really don't know which application that I can choose. Anybody knows how to upload to appengine? Thank You

Comment: Please post the exact message you get when trying to upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "appcfg.sh" command will only work on Linux and Mac OS terminals. For Windows, try running this:

```
appengine-java-sdk\bin\appcfg.cmd update <war file location>
```

Moving forward, you can use this webpage as your reference in deploying to App Engine:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp

Hope this helps...